# Archive Build issue

Tags: react-native

When I try to archive my app in Xcode 11.2.1 it returns the error:

> ld: could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1200.0.32.2.0_0' Reader: '1100.0.33.12_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 11.0.0, (clang-1100.0.33.12)' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Check the iOS deployment target version is the same in PROJECT and TARGET